# Can Ubuntu Server 20.04 64-Bit boot from USB device on RPi 3B+?

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi

It boots for RPi4 from USB device, so I assumed it would also for the RPi3B+. However, I have not had any luck so far. Is there some extra step needed, or do I fundamentally need to boot from SD card and mount the file system separately? (I'm surprised how little comes up when googling this.)

Comment: [perhaps a useful reference](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89587/raspberry-pi-3b-installing-ubuntu-server-64bit-problems)

Comment: [see this page.](https://www.instructables.com/Booting-Raspberry-Pi-3-B-With-a-USB-Drive/) According to it the model 3B+ should boot from USB out of the box. No changes are needed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried booting a third time, this time from a different USB slot, and it worked! RPi3B+ Ubuntu does boot from USB out of the box.

Edit: I am finding that all three RPi3B+ units in my cluster are consistently failing to find my USB SSD device if inserted in the two USB slots not right next to the ethernet socket.